# Need script or software to remove unpaired reads from paired end reads

Tags: dna-sequence

I want to use AMOScmp to analyze illumina paired end data. AMOScmp requires the same number of paired file to build .afg file. The original fq files are paired. After I pass fq files separately through quality, duplicated sequences, and human DNA control, I find out that the paired end fa files have different number of reads. I want to remove unpaired reads from paired end reads to get two fa files with the same number of reads. Does anybody have script or know what software to help me to solve the problem?

Comment: What's the format of the read IDs?  For example, do paired reads off a given sequence fragment end in /1 and /2, with the preceding characters being identical between the two?  If so, it may make things easier to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [trimmomatic](http://www.usadellab.org/cms/?page=trimmomatic) utility to do this.  This is a quality trimming program that will output 4 files: R1_paired, R2_paired, R1_singles, R2_singles

If you just need the pairs to be matched then just run it with a single quality attribute like:

> MINLEN:20

NOTE:  You should be aware that if you need to shuffle the two paired end files later, the sequence parity between the two 'paired' files will not be 1:1 after some number of reads.  I suspect this is due to the threading that trimmomatic has.  If you are concerned about it be sure to set the threads to 1.  Not sure if this is a solution so verify the results by looking at random lines in both files.  Choose lines from the beginning, middle, and end of both files.  Then compare the sequence ID lines:

> head -n 1000 R1_paired.fastq | tail -n 4
>
> head -n 1000 R2_paired.fastq | tail -n 4

Here is an example using two paired end FASTQ files (NOTE: this assumes the input files are named R1.fastq and R2.fastq, and that the trimmomatic-0.30.jar is in the local directory, otherwise you will need to put the path for java to follow)

> java -jar ./trimmomatic-0.30.jar PE -threads 1 -phred33 R1.fastq R2.fastq R1_paired.fastq R1_singles.fastq R2_paired.fastq R2_singles.fastq MINLEN:20